# Tiles for tiff images in java ? or java wrapper for libTiff?

Tags: java, image, jakarta-ee, image-processing

I am converting pdf to tiff images for one of my project.
Than I using iipserver to generate tiles for the tiff images on fly. But this process is killing my CPU.

so I thinking of generating tile in advance and showing them directly instead of using iipserver. I researched into iipserver and got this libTiff c++ utility which is doing tiling work for the same server.

So I wanted to know is there any java wrapper for this libTiff or are there any other method from which i could generate tiles directly from tiff image or directly from pdf pages to tiles?

Comment: FYI, it should be pretty easy to call libtiff, or any other C/C++ library for that matter, directly from Java with [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/)

Comment: Hi samuel Audet.. I tried JavaCPP.. could u help me out with this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717582/want-to-call-c-code-from-java-code-using-javacpp

Comment: Ok, seems to have been resolved. Let me know if any more questions arise. You may also post them on the mailing list of JavaCPP to make sure I get them, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end , I got the solution. There are few points that I want to explain

- 1) Tiles parameter in any tiff image is just a metadata value, so
  there is nothing physically marking of tiles in an image

That best way I found to generate tiles out of image is BufferedImage class method:

```
 bufferedImage.getSubimage(x, y, w, h)
```

Now play with this method in a loop for image matrix as per your needs.
It worked 200% perfect for me.. cheers to all :)

Answer (score 0):

[ImageJ](http://code.imagej.net/trac/imagej) can handle Tiled Pyramidal TIFF. [JAI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/) can handle MipMaps generated from TIFF files as well.

And if you're looking for a ready-made solution, take a look at [djatoka](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/djatoka/index.php?title=Overview).