# Want to call C++ code from Java code using JavaCPP?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to call c++ code from java code by using JavaCPP.

I am trying to run there own example of LegacyLibrary on http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/

when I try to compile code with following command mentioned at site only

```
 javac -cp javacpp.jar:. LegacyLibrary.java
```

I get the following exception on console
[image]

**I don't under where I am wrong. I am specifying the path of jar which contains com.google.javacpp.* classes.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on Windows, so you should be using `;`, not `:` as a separator for the elements in your classpath.

Try with:

```
javac -classpath javacpp.jar;. ....
```

(Assuming that jar file is indeed in your current directory.)